# Implement IOS7 App Switcher Animation to change views

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, ios7

I'm trying to implement the effect bellow to switch my views:

(Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to post images, but is the same animation of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815091/how-do-i-make-the-swipe-to-kill-animation-that-is-used-in-the-ios-7-app-switcher))

I have a UIPageViewController with some views. Suppose this UIPageViewController is inside a ViewController with a header. In this header, there is a button when pressed will zoom out and show the views inside the UIPageController with the same look and feel of the app switcher. I don't have to swipe to up to delete these views. I just need the zoom out, scroll left-right and zoom in (at the end) look and feel.

Someone had already implemented this animation?

Comment: Can you clarify, are you trying to recreate the multitasking view? or are you trying to recreate the swipe like in the other question?

Comment: Michael, thanks for your interest. I did update the post description to try clarify my doubt. Tell me if it's is necessary some other information. Best regards!